# package.json isn't updated after installing or uninstalling package on my react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

On my react project, I make use of **http-proxy-middleware** to set up the proxy for communication between my frontend and backend. However, at some point in the development of my project, the packages installed and uninstalled no longer triggers the update on **package.json**. Not only that, I always see a line of code "**rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx**" in my command terminal after typing either **npm install or npm uninstall**. However, I still can use those packages in my app without running into any problem. It's just that they aren't shown on **package.json**. What's the possible cause for this problem?